# Sagemaker FeatureGroup create() not making a 'Parameters' key in the Glue Catalog Table metadata

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Okay, here's a code snippet:

```
from sagemaker.feature_store.feature_group import FeatureGroup

# Create a Feature Group and load our Feature Definitions
my_feature_group = FeatureGroup(name=self.output_uuid, sagemaker_session=self.sm_session)
my_feature_group.load_feature_definitions(data_frame=self.output_df)

my_feature_group.create(
            s3_uri=s3_storage_path,
            record_identifier_name=self.id_column,
            event_time_feature_name=self.event_time_column,
            role_arn=self.sageworks_role_arn,
            enable_online_store=True,
            tags=aws_tags
        )
```

This code works fine, the feature group is created and a glue data catalog/table is auto created, the problem is that the glue table doesn't have a 'Parameters' in it's meta data. So that makes later calls like `upsert_table_parameters` not work (you get a KeyError 'Parameters' not found)

```
 # This doesn't work (without hack below)
 wr.catalog.upsert_table_parameters(
            parameters=meta,
            database=self.data_catalog_db,
            table=self.table_name,
            boto3_session=self.boto_session,
        )
```

I can work around this after the feature group is created by making a boto3 glue client, pulling the table meta... adding a Parameters key and then calling `glue_client.update_table()` but that seems like the hard way around.

Looking for suggestions on having the glue table that the feature group creates automatically include a Parameters key?

Comment: @Brain what type of parameters are you looking Feature Store to automatically create?